# handling session Timeout in javascript or server side

Tags: javascript, php, session, settimeout, session-timeout

I have a website and currently I am handing the timeout on client side that is using Javascript, so that I no request is being made I log the user out, but I have seen people on SO suggesting the same approach , and I see a big lapse in it, suppose a user has 2 tabs open.

```
Tab 1:
www.MYSITE.com/welcome.php

Tab 2: 
www.MYSITE.com/edit_profile.php
```

Now if user is on Tab 2 and he is editing the profile there, Tab 1 is idle that means user will be logged out/shown warning (the way you are handling Idle time).

So that doesn't seems to be consistent, in my thinking it should be on server side, is my approach correct?

Comment: It seems that it really depends upon what the session is for and what your motivation is for closing the session after a specific amount of time.  If it's a cut/dry security issue, then you can only enforce that on the server - period.  If it's merely to detect some client inactivity and doesn't have immediate security issues, then it's fine to detect activity on the client.

Comment: @jfriend00 normally we use timeout for logging the person out..

Comment: And how important is that?  Are there security implications?  And, do you care if there are two tabs open and one causes a logout while the user is interacting in the other?  This all depends upon what's important to your application.  There is no other answer than that.

Comment: @jfriend00 correct..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be,

In case of Ajax, Whenever you send any request to server, on server you can check if session expired using `isset($_SESSION['variable'])`, send a response `SESSION_TIMEOUT` & then in ajax callback, check for this response.

If this is found, show user a message 'SESSION expired!' & redirect to initial page (may be login page).